# How can i show shortest path with ant-path-leaflet?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core, leaflet

```
 var latlngs = [
                [44.0567000, 12.5552968],
                [44.0567000, 12.5460868]
            ]; 
 const path = L.polyline.antPath(latlngs, {
                "delay": 400,
                "dashArray": [
                    10,
                    20
                ],
                "weight": 5,
                "color": "#0000FF",
                "pulseColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "paused": false,
                "reverse": false,
                "hardwareAccelerated": true
            });
            const mymap2 = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 13);

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(mymap2);

            mymap2.addLayer(path);
            mymap2.fitBounds(path.getBounds())
```

In this example: https://rubenspgcavalcante.github.io/leaflet-ant-path/ map show the shortest path, but in my case map show a straight line.
My code is equal to the example code, I think.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the correct layer?  Press Documentation in upper left corner of like.  Then search for options.  I think you need to set an option.

Comment: The ant-path plugin not searching the shortest way for you, it only animate the dotted line. To get the shortest way you have to use a routing plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,you need to know the `ant-path plugin` is not used to search the shortest way for you,it just displays the path by latitude and longitude which is set by yourself.

If you want to display the the route,you need set more latitude and longitude.

Here is a working demo like below:

```
<div id="map"></div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
          crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="~/lib/leaflet-ant-path-bower-master/leaflet-ant-path-bower-master/dist/leaflet-ant-path.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #heading {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            background: #333;
            color: #CCC;
        }
        a {
            color: #3388ff;
        }
        #map {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
        }
        .leaflet-canvas-layer {
            opacity: 0.55;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center:[44.057039, 12.551160],
            zoom: 11,
            maxzoom: 18,
            minzoom: 1,
            zoomControl: false,  
            editable: true, 
        });   
       L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

        //add more latitude and longitude
        let arrs = [
        [44.0567000, 12.5552968],
        [44.056880, 12.555297],
        [44.056955,12.553081],
        [44.057004, 12.551313],
        [44.057039, 12.551160],
        [44.056712, 12.547406],
        [44.056737, 12.547216],
        [44.0567000, 12.5460868]
                ];
    var antPath = L.polyline.antPath;
    var path = antPath(arrs, {
        "paused": false,   　　
        "reverse": false,　　
        "delay": 3000,　　　　
        "dashArray": [10, 20],　
        "weight": 5,　　　　
        "opacity": 0.5,　　
        "color": "#0000FF",　
        "pulseColor": "#FFFFFF"　　
    });
    path.addTo(map);
    </script>               
}
```

Result:
[image]